# Surfaceview performance when under other layouts

Tags: android, surfaceview, frame-rate, android-view, performance

My app has an Activity where I display a surfaceview using a classic game loop/thread.

I tested 2 scenarios :

- Screen displaying only the Surfaceview : **60 FPS**
- Screen displaying 1 Surfaceview under several other framelyouts/linearlayouts : **30 FPS !!**

The difference is so big, it seems view traversing is really expensive. Can anyone confirm this ? If so, is there any way to improve performance when using surfaceview+layouts ?

Comment: Do you mean your SurfaceView is inside the other layouts? Also, is your code any different? Or is it 100% the same? Do you do a findViewById inside the game loop?